# Angular to pass params as array (eg. ?category[]=1&category[]=2&category[]=3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to send an array through the $http.get() method in AngularJS. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$http.get('/events.json', {params: {category_id: [1,2]}});
```

I'm expecting this to be sent as /events.json?category_id[]=1&category_id[]=2 but it is instead being sent as /events.json?category_id=[1,2]

Any ideas how I could correct this?

Comment: Maybe try `{params: "category_id[]=1&category_id[]=2"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, although pretty annoying that I had to use jQuery (AngularJS team you're slacking!).

```
var queryString = decodeURIComponent($.param({ category_id: $scope.checkedCategories }));
$http.get('/events.json?' + queryString);
```

Comment: Is that `decodeURIComponent` really necessary? Seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
$http.get('/events.json', {params: {category_id[]: 1, category_id[]: 2}});
```

Comment: This cannot work (even if the syntax error was fixed) because javascript will only keep the most recent key

Comment: Try making `category_id[]` a string, and adding indexes.  `params: {'category_id[0]': 1, 'category_id[1]': 2}`

Comment: Rocket Hazmat: Your suggestion is definitely the best so far, but it's coming out as category_id"=>{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"} instead of category_id"=>["1", "2"] on the backend.